# C++ Confusion. Reading Integer From Text File. Convert to ASCII

Tags: c++, char, ascii, new-operator, int

I am learning C++ for the first time.  I have no previous programming background.

In the book I have I saw this example.

```
#include <iostream>

using::cout;
using::endl;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    char y = char(x);

    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The example makes sense: print an integer and the ASCII representation of it.

Now, I created a text file with these values.

```
48
49
50
51
55
56
75
```

I am writing a program to read this text file -- "theFile.txt" -- and want to convert these numbers to the ASCII value.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

int main()
{
    ifstream thestream;
    thestream.open("theFile.txt");

    char thecharacter;  

    while (thestream.get(thecharacter))
    {
        int theinteger = int(thecharacter);
        char thechar = char(theinteger);
        cout << theinteger << "\t" << thechar << endl;
    }


    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my understanding about the second program shown.

- The compiler does not know the exact data type that is contained in "theFile.txt".  As a result, I need to specify it so I choose to read the data as a char.
- I read the each digit in the file as a char and converted it to an integer value and stored it in "theinteger".
- Since I have an integer in "theinteger" I want to print it out as a character but char thechar = char(theinteger); does not work as intended.

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: So, what *does* your program do right now?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `using std::cout;`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing my mistake.  I posed the wrong code. Will update it in a few minutes.

Comment: This is the type of first questions we miss seeing on SO. Congrats.

Comment: This is completely off-track, so I write it just as a comment. If you can get a hold of Accelerated C++, do take a look into it. It has a completely different approach to learning C++, starting with STL and high level constructs and going down into detail from there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I was planning to go to the book store later today, and will look for that book.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Based on the responses, I have figured out my mistake.  If interested, I can post the final version but it is much straightforward even for me once I figured out what I did incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading one char at a time from the file. Hence, if your file contains:

```
2424
```

You will first read the char "2" from the file, convert it to an int, and then back to a char, which will print "2" on cout. Next round will print "4", and so on.

If you want to read the numbers as full numbers, you need to do something like:

```
int theinteger;
thestream >> theinteger;
cout << char(theinteger) << endl;
```

Comment: Oh, I get it.  A (char)acter is a single.  Oh my for my dumb mistake.

Answer (score 6):

You are reading char by char, but you really (I think) want to read each sequence of digits as an integer.  Change your loop to:

```
int theinteger; 
while (thestream >> theinteger )
{
    char thechar = char(theinteger);
    cout << thechar << endl;
}
```

+1 For a very nicely formatted & expressed first question, BTW!

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Neil.  I want to read each number as completely.  Each number is on its own line.  Is it common to make oversights like this as in you intend to do something but you use the incorrect commands?  I hope that makes sense.